# How to set more than a filter over JSON data using JSON_VALUE?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I'm just trying to set a query to get data from a collection of object JSON:

```
create table test (LINE_SPECS nvarchar(max));

insert into test values (N'
 {
  "lineName":"GHjr",
  "pipeDiameter":"12",
  "pipeLength":"52000",
  "pressure":"15",
  "volume":"107"
 },
 {
  "lineName":"Ks3R",
  "pipeDiameter":"9",
  "pipeLength":"40000",
  "pressure":"15",
  "volume":"80"
 }
');
```

Now, as getting lineName of the first object ( lineName : Ghjr) is a success

```
    select
      JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.lineName')     as line_name
    , JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.pipeDiameter') as diameter

from test
WHERE JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.lineName') = 'GHjr' 
;
```

that is not possible when I try to get the second that is "Ks3R" :

```
    select
      JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.lineName')     as line_name
    , JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.pipeDiameter') as diameter

from test
WHERE JSON_VALUE(LINE_SPECS, '$.lineName') = 'Ks3R'
```

How can I do that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your `JSON` data isn't valid, it might be an array.

look like this.

```
create table test (LINE_SPECS nvarchar(max));

insert into test values (N'
  [
  {
  "lineName":"GHjr",
  "pipeDiameter":"12",
  "pipeLength":"52000",
  "pressure":"15",
  "volume":"107"
 },
 {
  "lineName":"Ks3R",
  "pipeDiameter":"9",
  "pipeLength":"40000",
  "pressure":"15",
  "volume":"80"
 }
]');
```

You can try to use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `CROSS APPLY` to parse `JSON` and make it.

```
select
     t2.*
from test t1 
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(t1.LINE_SPECS)
    WITH
        (
            line_name varchar(MAX) N'$.lineName',
            diameter varchar(MAX) N'$.pipeDiameter'
        ) AS t2
WHERE line_name  = 'Ks3R'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f4ac1979e93ac3ec99748e8d30b02d41)

Comment: really good catch on the malformed JSON.  I wish I could upvote twice, once for getting the data right and once for getting the solution right ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day.